# Move image to server after AJAX upload

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading

I´m capturing an image and upload this to a .php-script on my server. The AJAX upload works fine, but i don´t know how to handle the uploaded image within php...

```
    // Upload files to server
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    path = mediaFile.fullPath;
    name = mediaFile.name;

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=mediaFile.name;
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.fullpath = path;
    params.name = name;

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload( path, "http://example.de/db/uploadPhoto.php",
        function(result) {
            alert("success");         
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("error");
        },
        options
        );
}
```

The upload.php file:

```
<?php     
$uploaddir = '/home/strato/http/premium/rid/21/46/53452146/htdocs/tellthedj_dev/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Datei ist valide und wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen.\n";
} else {
    echo "Möglicherweise eine Dateiupload-Attacke!\n";
}

echo 'Weitere Debugging Informationen:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

can you tell me what i have to do in php to move the file to a direction on my server?
Like i said, the upload works fine...

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder in which u want to move the image to ? (chmod)

Comment: The permissions of the folder are 755... should do it

Comment: it always responses "echo "Möglicherweise eine Dateiupload-Attacke!\n";"

Comment: Did u try : 
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'Valid file';
}

Comment: yeah, still the same....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home/strato/http/premium/rid/..../".$new_image_name);
?>
```